# Thymeleaf how to output an Object array for Google Chart

Tags: spring-boot, google-visualization, thymeleaf

Examples for Google Charts with Thymeleaf are really lacking. I don't want to create a HTTP endpoint for every single graph which is the approach taken here:  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-api-metrics although it's a good guide otherwise.

I just want to know how Thymeleaf can output an object array `Object[][]` to the javascript string representation that the charts API can ingest. It Must (capital M) be possible.

As far as I can see from reading the documentation, the syntax I used should have worked. Please advise

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
        'packages' : [ 'corechart' ]
    });

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var d = /*[[${tools}]]*/  ;
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(d);

    var options = {
        title: 'Test data generated by tool',
        pieHole: 0.4,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('data_chart');
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping("portal")
String index(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("metrics", metricsService.getMetricsForHomePage());
    model.addAttribute("tools", metricsService.getToolMetricsForHomePage());
    return "index";
}
```

**service**

```
@Override
public Object[][] getToolMetricsForHomePage() {

    int rowCount = (int) testToolRepository.count();
    Object[][] result = new Object[rowCount][2];

    int i = 0;
    for (TestTool t : testToolRepository.findAll()){
        result[i][0] = t.getName();
        result[i][1] = t.getGeneratedDataCount();
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Thymeleaf inline annotation on the script tag:

`<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">`

This will turn on the inlining feature.